# Convert String to DateTime format of google APIs

Tags: android, datetime, google-api

I have a String which I have retrieved from a editText which receives the date from a date picker fragment. Now i need to convert this to DateTime format which the Google Calendar API needs while creating events. I have not been able to do it. It might be very silly but i am stuck here for quite sometime now.

```
     String dateString = start_date.toString();
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd"); 
     DateTime sdate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

When i try something like this i get cannot convert string to DateTime format error

Comment: what is your start_date?

Comment: use `MM` instead of `mm`, refer to [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
        String mytime="Jan 17, 2012";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "MMM dd, yyyy");
        Date myDate = null;
        try {
            myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

        System.out.println(finalDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
String dateString = "2012/09/24";
String[] arr = dateString.split("/");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.set(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]),Integer.parseInt(arr[1]),Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
         Date date = c.getTime();

System.out.println(date);
```